# 'Decimal' object is not iterable when trying to extend list

Tags: python

I have the following -

```
db = mariadb.connect(host=host,
                     user=someuser,
                     passwd=somepass)

cursor = db.cursor(mariadb.cursors.DictCursor)

#Get the top 5 largest tables inside of the database
cursor.execute('SELECT table_schema as `Database`, table_name AS `Table`, round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB`  FROM information_schema.TABLES  ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC LIMIT 5;')
data = cursor.fetchall()

for item in data:
   dbsize.extend(float(item['Size in MB']))
```

This is giving me the following error -

`'Decimal' object is not iterable`

If I just print them (instead of adding them to a list) it prints out the correct values.  How can I get this code to add each item to this list successfully?  I tried changing them to floats, but got the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: `append` is "add this thing". `extend` is "add all of the things inside this thing". You want `append`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `append` instead of `extend`.
see:

> L.extend(iterable) -> None -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable

```
a = []
In [131]: from decimal import Decimal

In [132]: f = Decimal(23.12)

In [133]: f
Out[133]: Decimal('23.120000000000000994759830064140260219573974609375')

In [134]: a.extend(f)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-13e0f548b372> in <module>()
----> 1 a.extend(f)

TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object is not iterable

In [135]: a.append(f)

In [136]: a
Out[136]: [Decimal('23.120000000000000994759830064140260219573974609375')]
```

Comment: You should probably mention how you got that information (like `help(list.extend)` or [the online help](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types))

Comment: @DanielH Thanks for suggestion, i was updating the answer continuously.

Comment: Fair enough. I would usually find a few more words helpful, but at least this says what went wrong as well as how to fix it.

Comment: @DanielH What more i can write please suggest?

Comment: I updated my comment,because I didn’t know if you’d seen it, to mention linking to the documentation or mentioning the `help` function; you can also add the same information about your suggested alternative approach of `append`, not just `extend`.